# Paste selected range from one xls file to another into a designated sheet and cell - "Copy method of Range class failed"

Tags: c#, excel

I wrote code which works only on xlsx files, if I run it with xls files I get "Copy method of Range class failed". I need a solution which will work with specifically xls files.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class Xls: CopyPaste
{
    public override void Run() {
        String srcPath = "C:\\test1.xls";
        Excel.Application xlsSrcApp;
        xlsSrcApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook srcXls = xlsSrcApp.Workbooks.Open(srcPath);
        Excel.Worksheet srcWrks = (Excel.Worksheet)srcXls.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        Excel.Range srcRange;

        String destPath = "C:\\test2.xls";
        Excel.Application xlsDestApp;
        xlsDestApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook destXls = xlsSrcApp.Workbooks.Open(destPath, 0, false);
        Excel.Worksheet destWrks = (Excel.Worksheet)xlsDestApp.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        Excel.Range destRange;

        Excel.Range srcRange = srcWrks.Range["A1:B2"];
        Excel.Range destRange = destWrks.Range["A10"];

        srcRange.Copy(destRange);

        destXls.SaveAs(destPath);

        xlsSrcApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False;
        srcXls.Close(true, null, null);
        xlsSrcApp.Quit();

        xlsDestApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False;
        destXls.Close(true, null, null);
        xlsDestApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with c# syntax but in VBA, when we copy syntax is **`<copy from range>.Copy <copy to rang>`** (i.e. `srcRange.Copy destRange`). Also, you are opening `destXls` workbook using the original instance of excel application (`xlsSrcApp`) but when you attempt to assign `destWrks` worksheet, you are using `xlsDestApp`. Not sure if that would work as workbook is opened in `xlsSrcApp` instance. Again not too familiar with c# so it might just be my lack of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are opening the Excel files in 2 instances of the Excel Application.

Try this, it works for me.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class Xls: CopyPaste
{
    public override void Run() {
        string srcPath = "C:\\test1.xls";
        Excel.Application xlsSrcApp;
        xlsSrcApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook srcXls = xlsSrcApp.Workbooks.Open(srcPath);
        Excel.Worksheet srcWrks = (Excel.Worksheet)srcXls.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        Excel.Range srcRange;

        string destPath = "C:\\test2.xls";
        Excel.Workbook destXls = xlsSrcApp.Workbooks.Open(destPath, 0, false);
        Excel.Worksheet destWrks = (Excel.Worksheet)destXls.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        Excel.Range destRange;

        srcRange = srcWrks.Range["A1:B2"];
        destRange = destWrks.Range["A10"];

        srcRange.Copy(destRange);

        //No need to do SaveAs you set SaveChanges on Close to true
        //destXls.SaveAs(destPath);

        xlsSrcApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
        srcXls.Close();
        destXls.Close(true);
        xlsSrcApp.Quit();
    }
}
```